# sort collection by custom new value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query below, I need to sort the Cars by a value that is collected from another table:

```
$cars = Car::paginate(100);
$cars->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
.....
....
...
$item['buy_date'] = Transaction::where('id', $item->buy_transaction)->first()->date;

});
```

I tried:

```
->sortBy('buy_date')
```

But it didn't sort the result.

Comment: What does getCollection() do?

Comment: I use it for transforming with pagination: https://gist.github.com/Repox/7784159810681db92b87ca44d5a9464d

Comment: Ah. I don't think you can sort on pagination. You should sort the data before calling ->paginate(). You can add a value to getCollection('buy_date') and sort it there before paginating the reply.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, why can't I sort on pagination? and in my case I have many key=>value pairs I add in the collection that I need to sort with them, and they are from other tables or calculated using several methods..

Comment: You have to sort before you paginate. Makes sense right? It takes 15 records of your database and returns them. Sorting them later on doesn't make any sense. How can laravel figure out what is in the 2nd page of pagination? You can paginate on any complexity, but after that the object is what it is. If you dd() on a paginated result, you'll see why that is.